# How do I determine the origin device when completing a fulfillment request for Actions on Google?

Tags: actions-on-google

Title is essentially it.

When performing the fulfillment logic of an action, is there any means to determine the originating device where the query / prompt was made? A unique (persistent) device ID, a device name, anything that can be associated to the device in question?

i.e. when I say `Hey Google, make me a martini`, is there a way for the fulfillment logic to determine that I was talking to my Google Home in the living room, and not the one in my bedroom (or my phone)?

Answer (score 0):

There used to be. As far as I know it is no longer available.